# Approximation bounds for matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, matrix-analysis, matrix-equations, linear-matrix-inequalities

$\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{\mathrm{op}}$Since matrix multiplication is continuous, I expect that if $A_n\to A\in \mathrm{Mat}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})$ for the operator-norm and if $x_n\to x$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ then
$$
\left\|A_n x_n - Ax\right\|\to 0.
$$

However, I cannot manage to derive a reasonable bound for this, where by "reasonable" I mean that:
$$
\left\| B y - Ax \right\| \leq p(\|B-A\|_{\op},\|y-x\|),
$$
for some non-negative continuous function $p:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ converging to $0$ as its arguments converge to $0$ and *does not* depend on the quantities $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$.

To date, the best I have gotten is
$$
\left\| B y - Ax \right\| \leq \min\left\{
\|B\|_{\op}\|x-y\| + \|A-B\|_{\op}\|y\|
,
\|A\|_{\op}\|x-y\| + \|A-B\|_{\op}\|x\|
\right\},
$$
but this is of no use to me since the bound depends on $\|x\|$ and on $\|y\|$.

---

Are such bounds possible?  What if I also assume that $A,B \in \mathrm{SO}(d,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Consider the case $x=y$.  Then $By-Ax=(B-A)x$ so $\|By-Ax\|\le \|(B-A)\| \, \|x\|$ with equality if $x$ is an eigenvector of $B-A$ no matter how small $B-A$ is.  So there is no bound like you suggested, but as Geoff said you don't need it just to prove convergence.

Comment: You don't need what you ask for just to prove that $A_{n}x_{n} \to Ax$ when $A_{n} \to A$ and $x_{n} \to x$. Just write $A_{n}x_{n}- Ax$ as $(A_{n}-A)(x_{n}-x) + A(x_{n}-x) + (A_{n}-A)x.$

Comment: Yes, to prove convergence I can just use the fact that function evaluation is continuous in the compact-open topology on locally-compact domains.  But I was asking more to helop me derive some convergence bounds...